# SP online document library can be crawled from SP 2016 server

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

Hi we have a scenario where we have a SP online site like https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/finance and we want to do search crawl of this site from a SharePoint on primise server. I understand we can crawl the SharePoint on primise data from SP online search application using hybrid search but whether from On prmise server we can crawl Sp online content is possible?